# OpenGL buffer woes

Tags: c++, opengl-es, buffer

I've been getting back into OpenGL recently after transitioning to linux. For some reason or another, things like `glGenBuffers`, `glBindBuffer`, etc, aren't present with the normal GL headers, and cause my program to crash using GLEW. To get around this I've been using GLES2.

And now the problem:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

int main() {
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "OpenGL Tests");

  glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 480, -1, 1);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

  //x, y, r, g, b
  GLfloat triangleVertices[15] = {
    10, 10, 1, 0, 0,
    110, 10, 0, 1, 0,
    60, 96.6f, 0, 0, 1
  };
  GLuint triangleBuf;

  glGenBuffers(1, &triangleBuf);
  glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, triangleBuf);
  glBufferData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, sizeof(triangleVertices), triangleVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, 0);

  while(window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;

    while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
      if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, triangleBuf);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 3, 0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 2, (GLfloat*) 2);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    window.display();
    sf::sleep(sf::milliseconds(50));
  }

  glDeleteBuffers(1, &triangleBuf);
}
```

This is how I remember using buffers, though to be honest I don't trust my memory. With good reason it seems, since this crashes immediately after the window opens.

I've tried changing the last argument to `glDrawArrays` to 1 instead of 3. I've also tried binding the buffer twice, first as `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`, followed by `glVertexPointer`, second as `GL_COLOR_ARRAY`, followed by `glColorPointer`. No dice.

Comment: I think your just confusing some constants here. `glBindBuffer` can't be used with `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`. See [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml). Did you mean `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) respectively [`glColorPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColorPointer.xml) is the  byte offset between consecutive (stride). If a named buffer object is bound, then the 4th parameter is treated as a byte offset, too.
The `stride` parameter has to be `5 * sizeof(GLfloat)`, because each attribute tuple consists of 5 (`GLfloat`) components (X, Y, R, G, B). The offset for the vertex coordinates is 0, because they are at the beginning. The offset for the color is `2 * sizeof(GLfloat)`, because the color comes after the 2 components of the vertex coordinate.

Further more `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` is not a valid buffer target. The buffer target for  vertex attributes is `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. The wrong usage of `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` will cause *INVALID_ENUM* errors. Error information can be get by [`glGetError`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml).

Do the following changes:

```cpp
glGenBuffers(1, &triangleBuf);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuf);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangleVertices), triangleVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuf);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLfloat*)(2*sizeof(GLfloat)));
```

---

Since you do not bind a texture and you do net even have specified texture coordinates, do not enable 2 dimensional texturing:

<s>`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`</s>

Comment: Thanks! Seeing "If stride is 0, the vertices are understood to be tightly packed" on the Khronos page for glVertexPointer made me think it referred to the space between the end of one vertex and the beginning of another.